# AppserviceresourcesDeployment fails When making a python web app using a PostgreSQL flexible database

Tags: python, postgresql

Getting the following errors when deploying a Python (Django or Flask) web app with PostgreSQL in Azure.  I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=flask%2Cwindows&pivots=deploy-portal) on microsoft learn.

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"message":"No available instances to satisfy this request. App Service is attempting to increase capacity. Please retry your request later. If urgent, this can be mitigated by deploying this to a new resource group."}]}
>
> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details."}]}

I have tried to redeploy the resource groups. Checked my eventwatcher showed it was 100% usage.